# How to build Boost.Beast on linux? The library is on github but won't be included in Boost until December

Tags: c++, linux, boost, build, compilation

How to build the [following library: Boost.Beast](https://github.com/boostorg/beast) (which will not be available in boost until Boost 1.66.0)?

[Reading the build instructions](https://github.com/boostorg/beast#building) they seem to be focused on Windows only:

```
cd ..
mkdir bin64
cd bin64
cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..    # for 64-bit Windows builds (VS2015)
cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..    # for 64-bit Windows builds (VS2017)
```

I've installed Boost which is a dependency of Beast (`include/boost/beast/config.hpp` includes `<boost/config.hpp>`) using:

```
sudo apt install libboost-dev
```

I've tried using `cmake .` and `make` to build the library which resulted in the below:

```
user:~/libraries/beast$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "1.0.2g") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/libraries/beast


user:~/libraries/beast$ make
[  0%] Building CXX object example/advanced/server/CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o
In file included from /home/user/libraries/beast/include/boost/beast/websocket/stream.hpp:3512:0,
                 from /home/user/libraries/beast/include/boost/beast/websocket.hpp:18,
                 from /home/user/libraries/beast/example/advanced/server/advanced_server.cpp:18:
/home/user/libraries/beast/include/boost/beast/websocket/impl/read.ipp: In member function ‘std::size_t boost::beast::websocket::stream<NextLayer>::read_some(const MutableBufferSequence&, boost::beast::error_code&)’:
/home/user/libraries/beast/include/boost/beast/websocket/impl/read.ipp:1077:49: warning: enumeral and non-enumeral type in conditional expression [-Wextra]
                     cr.code == close_code::none ?
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
                         close_code::normal : cr.code,
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[  0%] Linking CXX executable advanced-server
CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o: In function `std::thread::thread<main::{lambda()#1}>(main::{lambda()#1}&&)':
advanced_server.cpp:(.text+0x11a9): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
advanced_server.cpp:(.text+0x158c): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
advanced_server.cpp:(.text+0x1598): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
advanced_server.cpp:(.text+0x15a4): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
advanced_server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o: In function `boost::system::errc::make_error_condition(boost::system::errc::errc_t)':
advanced_server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system4errc20make_error_conditionENS1_6errc_tE[_ZN5boost6system4errc20make_error_conditionENS1_6errc_tE]+0x1c): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
advanced_server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[_ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv]+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o: In function `boost::beast::file_posix::close(boost::system::error_code&)':
advanced_server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost5beast10file_posix5closeERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost5beast10file_posix5closeERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x32): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o: In function `boost::beast::file_posix::open(char const*, boost::beast::file_mode, boost::system::error_code&)':
advanced_server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost5beast10file_posix4openEPKcNS0_9file_modeERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost5beast10file_posix4openEPKcNS0_9file_modeERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x39): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
advanced_server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost5beast10file_posix4openEPKcNS0_9file_modeERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost5beast10file_posix4openEPKcNS0_9file_modeERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x173): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
advanced_server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost5beast10file_posix4openEPKcNS0_9file_modeERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost5beast10file_posix4openEPKcNS0_9file_modeERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x1d8): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o: In function `boost::beast::file_posix::size(boost::system::error_code&) const':
advanced_server.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost5beast10file_posix4sizeERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZNK5boost5beast10file_posix4sizeERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/advanced_server.cpp.o:advanced_server.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost5beast10file_posix4sizeERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZNK5boost5beast10file_posix4sizeERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x7e): more undefined references to `boost::system::generic_category()' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
example/advanced/server/CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'example/advanced/server/advanced-server' failed
make[2]: *** [example/advanced/server/advanced-server] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:133: recipe for target 'example/advanced/server/CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [example/advanced/server/CMakeFiles/advanced-server.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: "advanced_server.cpp:(.text+0x158c): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'" -- you're either not linking against the right library or the library doesn't have the features listed.

Comment: Which version of boost was installed? Maybe it is too old?

Comment: @ead The installed version was 1.62

Comment: @xaxxon I've seen installed Boost 1.65 from source however the same error prevails.

Comment: How does your linking command looks? Does it have ` -lboost_system` ?

Comment: @ead I don't completely understand that. Boost is installed in `/usr/local/include/boost` and running `echo -e '#include <boost/version.hpp>\nBOOST_VERSION' | gcc -x c++ -E -` does yield the version number.

Comment: Obviously, the problem is linking. You have to provide the names of needed libs. It looks as if the name of `boost_system`  is not provided to the linker.

Comment: Beast requires Boost System library to be built AND linked with. This one is not header-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CMakeLists.txt only works for Windows, but the bjam build scripts work on all platforms. The docs could do a better job explaining this. However, note that Beast is header-only so you only need to use bjam or cmake if you are trying to build the examples or tests.

Comment: Thank you for responding :) 

Would you mind showing how users can build examples in linux?

Comment: Yes, please see https://github.com/boostorg/beast/pull/794/commits/04bf98298fb76e7620442b7ea92c4cc51a322ec2